# How to get fixed value from elegant number button in android?

Tags: android

I got trouble with elegant new button. I need to get a fixed value from it then store it in my database as number.

Here's what I have tried :

```
  number_b.setOnClickListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String num = number_b.getNumber();
            String foodid = mBundle.getString("Title");
            String price = mBundle.getString("Price");
            insertdata2(foodid , price, num);                           
        }
    });
```

Also this :

```
number_b.setOnValueChangeListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            String num = number_b.getNumber();
            String foodid = mBundle.getString("Title");
            String price = mBundle.getString("Price");
            insertdata2(foodid , price, num);
        }
    });
```

when I clicked until 3 from elegant number button, in the `sqlite` db browser show this (both of program) :

> foodid : icecream; price : 10000; num : 1
>
> foodid : icecream; price : 10000; num : 2
>
> foodid : icecream; price : 10000; num : 3

While I need it show in my `sqilite` browser like this :

> foodid : icecream; price : 10000; num : 3

Can you tell me which part is wrong in my program?. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting values in your database every time the value is changed. So when you click the button 3 times and the listener is called 3 times. So it stores values every time you click your button.
Try updating the value instead of inserting in the database.

Comment: What you need to do is to insert the value when it is clicked once and keep updating after that. You can use a bool flag to check if button is clicked more than once. If the button is clicked once then insert it and if its clicked more than once then update the value. If any error persists then post your database code snippet. @Juls